# The user has not authorized this application to perform the action in facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

I am trying to post on facebook wall from mysite using hybrid auth api in php but always get an exception/error "The user has not authorized this application to perform the action in facebook post".

Any Guess ??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you gather the `publish_actions` permission during Facebook Login. Also, this permission is subject to Login Review, meaning that if you didn't receive the permission yet, you'll only be able to use it with the app's admins/testers/developers.